# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 9D

Tags: java

I am trying to make a jar file run on my Linux server. On my Windows desktop I can execute the jar file just fine using the command:

```
java -Xss1000m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Xmx5048m -jar test.jar
```

However when I run it on my Linux server I get the following error:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 9D
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1374)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1988)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1912)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1795)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at com.test.test.Main.main(Main.java:41)
```

My code is:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String fromTextFile = "";
    String path = "";

    if (!SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS)
        path = "/var/www/tomcat/fetch/";

    fromTextFile = path + "resources/ac_geonames_country_all.txt";

    AhoCorasick tree = new AhoCorasick();

    ObjectInputStream ois;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fromTextFile));
        tree = (AhoCorasick) ois.readObject();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Serialized objects are not stored in a text file. So don’t give it a `txt` name ending. Otherwise make sure that your file transfer programs do not treat it like a text file using program options. If the transfer program applies line break and charset encoding conversions they will most likely will trash your file.

Comment: I tested that. WinSCP is set to automatic file transfer. I manually switched to binary mode for ac_geonames_country_all.txt file. The file size changed, but the error stayed the same.

Comment: How did you create the file, and what is the definition of the object(s) you are serializing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a user error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working. I recreated the files directly on the Linux server. And now everything is working fine. Either something is going wrong during the file transfer. Or Java serializes files differently on Linux. I have no clue.

@EJP thanks for pointing that out. Then the file transfer messes up the file.

Comment: Java doesn't serialize files differently on Linux.